# Issue with Discord Bot (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have a problem (I know this is some simple code, but it has the same sort of idea as the code I'm using for a mini game) and here's the code for it

the problem is that the bot sends `Type 'one'` when I type u?test but when I then type u?test one, it sends the `Type 'one'` message again before sending `You typed one` . How can I make it so that the bot, when I type `u?test one` doesn't send the `Type 'one'` message again?
[The code I have for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJki1.png)

The problem is, when I type `u?test` out I get this
[What happens when I type `u?test`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xvr4.png)

I've tried changing the switch statement with an if statement, changing the switch with
 `if(msg.content === 'test){}'`, but it doesn't work as well.

Would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is simple, check if the user enters the argument you require, if not, do something.

```js
if (args[1] === 'one') {
  msg.channel.send(`You typed one`)
} else {
  msg.channel.send(`Type 'one'`)
}
```